# Submit form automatically that is present inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have below code that I want to submit automatically on page reload. This is giving showing me a button "pay now" but I want to click that button automatically. I think that button is part of src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js". Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

```
<div class="container" name="payment_submit">
      <form action="{% url 'razorpay_response' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <!-- Note that the amount is in paise = 50 INR -->
          <input type="hidden" name="creator" value="{{creator}}" />
          <input type="hidden" name="sub_value" value="{{sub_value}}" />
          <script
                  src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
                  data-key="{{rzr_id}}"
                  data-subscription_id="{{sub_id}}"
                  data-name = "My Billing Label"
                  data-description ="Auth txn for {{sub_id}}"
          ></script>
          <input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using the JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("form").submit();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just trigger the click on the button by selecting it and using the `.click()` method to trigger it.

```
  document.querySelector("[data-key='{{rzr_id}}']").click();
```